# reference a view page with entity reference

Tags: views, entities

I have an entity reference field for referencing and rendering a teaser display of nodes.

I would like to be able to include a View page in the list. I this possible in some way?

Comment: I think that you would need to wrap the view in a custom node type (using EVA, Display Suite etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[View Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewreference) Module makes it possible

> Defines a field type View reference which creates a relationship to a
> Views display and allows the view to be displayed as the content of
> the field.

**OR**

[Entityreference View Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) Module is another solution

> This module provides an advanced Entity Reference widget that uses a
> view embedded in a modal dialog for selecting items.
>
> In the Field UI for the Entity Reference field select "View" as the widget

- Edit your Content Type or Entity
- Add or Edit the field with "Entity Reference"
- Next make sure your "field" - "widget type" is set to "View"

[image]

**Check for the following "field" settings in your content type field:**

- "View": make sure you select your "Entity Reference View Widget"
- Pass selected entity ids to view

[image]